# How do i grep first character in each word in a paragraph

Tags: linux, unix, grep

Anyone please help me to solve this, I want to grep first character in each word, as this example:

```
Input: this is first , [test sentence] .this is second — test sentence ?

Result: t i f , [t s] .t i s — t s ?
```

Ignore any other character not in the alphabet table (special character as : , [ ] . :).

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `sed` to replace the matched pattern:

```
$ echo 'this is first , [test sentence] .this is second — test sentence ?' | \
  sed -r 's/(\w)\w*/\1/g'
t i f , [t s] .t i s — t s ?
```

Comment: could you please explain your answer a bit ,i hope i could understand that command ,thanks

Comment: @KimNguyen, I used [Capturing group](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html)(`(\w)`) to match the first character and the rest (`\w*`) and replace it with only with the first character (`\1`, backreference to the first group).